# SPA multiple JQuery document.ready()

Tags: jquery, ajax

Was wondering if anyone has some insight into a sound way of doing the following. I'm writing a single page app with a templating engine. The 'main' page has its own `$(document).ready()`, but what should I do for other ajax calls, that have their own `document.ready`? Let's say I load up the login page, which has it's own `document.ready` for form validation, so the page will have two of them, one from the layout, and one from the login script. Is this acceptable, or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: You can use AngularJS, because this framework is all about SPAs

Comment: You can keep each document.ready on its own page, and when loaded it will handle the content. Pay attention not to duplicate any ID

Comment: Can include `html` , `js` at Question ? What is purpose of multiple `.ready()` ? Tried using `.load()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is acceptable, jquery will handle the multiple calls. I would keep it this way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10335790)

Comment: @Guanxi Why isn't this answer? The OP asked if it's OK to have multiple document.ready handlers, he said it is.